# Disassembly Using Olly or IDA

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

Am new to reverse engineering and l get confused sometimes when l come across `LEA` instruction.
I want to get cleared on how to know if lea instruction is an array or a reference pointer.
Many people say that `LEA` instruction is used as a reference instruction

Eg: `lea ecx, [eax]` --meaning something like "int a=&b" in c++;

And some people say that it is used to load a content of a register into another register

Eg: `lea ecx, [eax]` --meaning the content of [eax] is loaded into ecx;

but l choose the first option. But where am confused is when l see something like this in olly:

```
lea ecx, dword ptr ss:[ecx+eax*2]
```

or

```
lea ecx, dword ptr ds:[ecx+eax*2]
```

and so on.

Please l need a clear explanation on the meaning of these instructions so as to know when it means a reference pointer or an array in C++ or even how to know the both(array and reference pointer) in olly or IDA.
l appreciate in advance.
Thanks.

Comment: better at [reverseengineering.se]

Answer (score -2):

In `C/C++` accessing a pointer or array is essentially the same thing. A straightforward `lea ecx, [eax]` is going to most likely be a pointer dereference, as there is no offset. Something more complicated like `lea ecx, dword ptr ss:[ecx+eax*2]` is likely an array access, as there is a base pointer (`ecx`) plus an index times size (`+eax*2`). There's no hard and fast rule for it.

Comment: `lea` does not perform a dereference, `mov` does.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky You make a good point. I had that wrong. I'm not certain what the point of `lea ecx, [eax]` would be instead of just using `mov ecx, eax`.

Comment: `lea ecx, [eax]` is pointless. but `lea ecx, dword ptr ss:[ecx+eax*2]` is just faster math (without having to read the extra operand from memory location)